# Is it possible to change the region of a Google Cloud Platform project?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

If I go to the [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project) then I can see all my Cloud Platform projects, but not their regions.

How do I see the region of each project? And is it possible to change the region once it has been set?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30170473/is-there-a-way-to-determine-or-specify-what-geo-region-bigquery-stores-data-in/30172227#30172227

Comment: Just found the docs specifying that region can't be changed: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing_jobs_datasets_projects#datasets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/#server-location

**Setting the server location**

When you create your project, you can specify the location from which it will be served. In the new project dialog, click on the link to Show Advanced Options, and select a location from the pulldown menu:

- us-central
- us-east1
- europe-west

If you select us-east1 your project will be served from a single region in South Carolina. The us-central and europe-west locations contain multiple regions in the United States and western Europe, respectively. Projects deployed to either us-central or europe-west may be served from any one of the regions they contain. If you want to colocate your App Engine instances with other single-region services, such as Google Compute Engine, you should select us-east1.

Comment: Ah OK. I want to change the region of a BigQuery dataset, is this possible?

Comment: You need to write to support.

Comment: I don't believe they will be able to help, what you can do is create another table on the desired location and copy your table there.

Comment: I'm not sure it's true that projects don't have regions. At least, when I create a new project from the Developer Console and use the advanced settings, it gives me options about which region I want it in.

Comment: You are right,
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/#server-location
When you create your project, you can specify the location from which it will be served. In the new project dialog, click on the link to Show Advanced Options, and select a location from the pulldown menu

Comment: The question here is about the location if can be set corresponding to a GCP project. Only the resources/services can be associated with the region. The link you have provided is for creating app engine in a specific location.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such thing as a region of a GCP project.
In other words, region/location is specific to resources, and a GCP project is not permanently tied to a single region/location.
For example, you can have a project with multiple BigQuery datasets in different regions.
That same project can have many Compute Engine instances running, each one in different location/region.

There is a [default region](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/changing-default-zone-region) that is set per GCP project, but that can always be overwritten when creating resources in GCP, and is mainly used to guess default location when location is not specified in API calls.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the BigQuery aspect of this question:

Data Locations on a table are immutable once set.

In order to change the location, the easiest solution would be to export the data to Google Cloud Storage, delete the table, re-create the table in the correct region, then import the data.

Comment: Note: A table's location is determined by its containing dataset. The dataset location must be set on creation (default US if unspecified), and is immutable.